# Which code can assign a new value to a variable when R is running? (like input() in VBA)

Tags: r, function, input, statistics

I am creating a function where some coefficients should be defined by users to improve the model.

I tried **scan()** , **readline()**, and others to input the value. But all of them will read the next line of my code instead of be paused and let the user input something in R Console.

Is there any code can achieve similar function like **input()** in VBA. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Which R and which platform are you running? If I source the following script : `a <- 1;
b <- readline("enter text : ");
c <- 2;` it stops and asks for input in between assigning a and c.

Comment: @user1981275 Thanks for your reply. I use R 3.0.3 under windows. I tried your code, but the result is like that below. I can assign some value to b, but it is after c<-2. Do you have any suggestion. Thank you so much!  [[[[> a <- 1; b <- readline("enter text : "); c <- 2;
enter text : 1]]]]